# AWS Lambda - Store state of a queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, state

I'm currently tasked with building a serverless architecture for communication between government agencies and citizens, and a main component is some form of queue that contains some form of object/pointer to each citizens request, sorted by priority. The government workers can then process an element when available. As Lambda is stateless, I need to save the queue outside in some manner.

For saving state I've gathered that you can use DynamoDB or S3 Buckets and use event triggers to invoke related Lambda methods. Some also suggest using Parameter Store to save some state variables. Storing things globally has also come up, though as you can't guarantee that the Lambda doesn't terminate, it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Finally, I've also read a bit about SQS, though I have no idea if it is at all applicable to this case.

What is the best-practice / suggested approach when working with Lambda in this way? I'm leaning towards S3 Buckets, due to event triggering, and not using DynamoDB as our DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Storing things globally has also come up, though as you can't guarantee that the Lambda doesn't terminate, it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Correct -- this is not viable at all.  Note that what you are actually referring to when you say "the Lambda" is the process inside the container... and any time your Lambda function is handling more than one invocation concurrently, you are *guaranteed* that they will not be running in the same container -- so "global" variables are only useful for optimization, not state.  Any two concurrent invocations of the same function have two entirely different global environments.

Forgetting all about Lambda for a moment -- I am not saying don't use Lambda; I'm saying that whether or not you use Lambda isn't relevant to the rest of what is written, below -- I would suggest that parallel/concurrent actions in general are perhaps one of the most important factors that many developers tend to overlook when trying to design something like you are describing.

How you will assign work from this work "queue" is extremely important to consider.  You can't just "find the next item" and display it to a worker.

You must have a way to do all of these things:

- finding the next item that appears to be available
- verify that it is indeed available
- assign it to a specific worker
- mark it as unavailable for assignment

Not only that, but you have to be able to do all of these things *atomically* -- as a single logical action -- and without collisions.

A naïve implementation runs the risk of assigning the same work item to two or more people, with the first assignment being blindly and silently overwritten by subsequent assignments that happen at almost the same time.

DynamoDB allows [conditional updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.SimpleComparisons) -- update a record if and only if a certain condition is true.  This is a critical piece of functionality that your solution needs to accommodate -- for example, assign work item x to user y if and only if item x is currently unassigned.  *A conditional update will fail, and changes nothing, if the condition is not true at the instant the update happens* and therein lies the power of the feature.

S3 does not support conditional updates, because unlike DynamoDB, S3 operates only on an [eventual-consistency model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel) in most cases.  After an object in S3 is updated or deleted, there is no guarantee that the next request to S3 will return the most recent version or that S3 will not return an item that has recently been deleted.  This is not a defect in S3 -- it's an optimization -- but it makes S3 unsuited to the "work queue" aspect.

Skip this consideration and you will have a system that appears to work, and works correctly much of the time... but at other times, it "mysteriously" behaves wrongly.

Of course, if your work items have accompanying documents (scanned images, PDF, etc.), it's quite correct to store them in S3... but S3 is the wrong tool for storing "state."  SSM Parameter Store is the wrong tool, for the same reason -- there is no way for two actions to work cooperatively when they both need to modify the "state" at the same time.

"Event triggers" are useful, of course, but from your description, the most notable "event" is not from the data, or the creation of the work item, but rather it is when the worker says "I'm ready for my next work item."  It is at that point -- triggered by the web site/application code -- when the steps above are executed to select an item and assign it to a worker.  (In practice, this could be browser → API Gateway → Lambda).  From your description, there may be no need for the creation of a new work item to trigger an "event," or if there is, it is not the most significant among the events.

You will need a proper database for this.  DynamoDB is a candidate, as is RDS.

The queues provided by SQS are designed to decouple two parts of your application -- when two processes run at different speeds, SQS is used as a buffer, allowing X to safely store the work needing to be done and then continue with something else until Y is able to do the work.  SQS queues are opaque -- you can't introspect what's in the queue, you just take the next message and are responsible for handling it.  On its face, that seems to partially describe what you need, but it is not a clean match for this use case.  Queues are limited in how long messages can be retained, and once a message is successfully processed, it is completely gone.

Note also that SQS is only a match to your use case with the FIFO queue feature enabled, which guarantees perfect in-order delivery and exactly-once delivery -- standard SQS queues, for performance optimization reasons, do not guarantee perfect in-order delivery and may under certain conditions deliver the same message more than once, to the same consumer or a different consumer.  But the SQS FIFO queue feature does not coexist with event triggers, which require standard queues.

So SQS may have a role, but you need an authoritative database to store the work and the results of the business process.

Comment: Very good answer, Michael. The only part I kind of disagree is when you mention S3 is not very suitable because it works with Eventual Consistency. The OP never mentioned updates, but only new objects instead. S3 has a read-after-write consistency so this should not be an issue. Without knowing more it's hard to tell, but I still think S3 could play a better role here since messages will need to be stored after they're read, which would an extra layer of complexity to the function, because it'd need to handle both SQS and a persistent storage. I am not saying it is hard, though.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi thanks for the feedback.  The "updates" I refer to would be updates to the "state."  You can't reliably use an S3 object or its metadata or tags to store state information -- next item to assign, item assignment status, etc.  You can't reliably use ListObjects to do things like "find the next" object, with the plan to then move or delete an object so a subsequent worker can't see it.  There will be collisions, where two workers see the same thing, encounter duplicates, etc.  These things will appear to work during dev, but fail "unexpectedly" in prod, due to concurrency.

Comment: ...and, of course, none of this is to be critical of S3, which is tremendously useful when applied correctly.  But S3 lacks any kind of atomic locking capability, as well as any metadata indexing/querying capability that compares meaningfully to what's offered by DynamoDB (or any proper database), both of which are essential for an application like this.  It might indeed be appropriate to store the requests, themselves, as objects in S3, but the management of the assignment database is not a good fit for S3.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, Michael! Much appreciated.

Comment: Let me first say, wow, greatly appreciate going above and beyond with giving such a detailed answer. In all honesty, while I knew consistency might be an issue, I hadn't given much thought into it, and your post has illuminated how naïve that was. Regarding which DB to use, we already use RDS Aurora for our main data-model, however, for whatever reason, I eliminated using it for the Queue, perhaps wrongly so. Does DynamoDB handle this sort of task better, or would it be preferable to use RDS, since for example I'll need to access the RDS DB in conjunction with the queue either way?

Comment: @PapoyEdits thanks.  I focused on DynamoDB primarily because you mentioned it, and because you use the phrase *"serverless architecture."* You may have been thinking primarily in terms of Lambda when you used that term, but DynamoDB is a serverless database.  If you're already interacting with RDS anyway, I would personally be inclined to use RDS for this part of the application as well, because SQL transactions can provide you with the same conditional updates, atomicity, and locking (e.g. using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to simultaneously fetch and lock a row).

Comment: So I've finally gotten around to implementing this, but I'm wondering about the SQL command. I'm using the Pony ORM, which generates this SQL:
"SELECT `i`.`id`, `i`.`session`, `i`.`timestamp`, `i`.`priority`, `i`.`device_id`, `i`.`role`, `i`.`status`
FROM `queue` `i`
WHERE `i`.`status` = 'Available'
ORDER BY `i`.`timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE

UPDATE `queue`
SET `status` = %s
WHERE `id` = %s"

My question is if this command would end up locking all entries that are 'Available' or only the first, as I have trouble actually testing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store the message, then SQS is not the best tool here, because your Lambda function would then need to process the message and finally store it somewhere, making SQS nothing but a broker.

The S3 approach gives what you need out of the box, considering you can store the files (messages) in an S3 bucket and then have one Lambda consume its event. Your Lambda would then process this event and the file would remain safe and sound on S3.

If you eventually need multiple consumers for this message, then you can send the S3 event to SNS instead and finally you could subscribe N Lambda Functions to a given SNS topic.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be worrying too much about the infrastructure at this stage and not enough on the application design. The fact that it will be **serverless** does not change the basic functionality of the application — it will still present a UI to users, they will still choose options that must trigger some business logic and information will still be stored in a database.

The **queue** you describe is merely a datastore of messages that are in a particular state. The application will have some form of business logic for determining the next message to handle, which could be based on creation timestamp, priority, location, category, user (eg VIP users who get faster response), specialization of the staff member asking for the next message, etc. This is not a "queue" but rather a calculation to be performed against all 'unresolved' messages to determine the next message to assign.

If you wish to go serverless, then the back-end will certainly be using Lambda and a database (eg DynamoDB or Amazon RDS). The application should store everything in the database so that data is available for the application's business logic. There is no need to use SQS since there really isn't a "queue", and Parameter Store is merely a way of sharing **parameters** amongst application components — it is not meant for core data storage.

Determine the application functionality first, then determine the appropriate architecture to make it happen.